# Solspace Tag custom placeholder

Tags: solspace, solspace-tag

I just updated tag to the latest version of Tag and noticed a placeholder "Press Enter after each Tag" has been added to the field.

How can I customise the the text here?

(All the fields across the site have placeholders instead of titles, so would be great to do this here too.)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is clear. You have two options. First, you can modify core files of Tag. This is totally not recommended, because you'll have to re-edit these files after every Tag module update... but for what you're looking to do, it's a pretty simple re-hack. You need to edit this file:

```
you_web_root/system/expressionengine/third_party/tag/language/english/lang.tag.php
```

Go to line 350, and it looks like this:

```
'press_enter_after_each_tags' =>
"Press [Enter] after each tag",
```

And edit the value of the key `press_enter_after_each_tags`.

Your other option, which will probably prevent you from having to edit that file after every Tag module update, is to make an EE Accessory. This allows you to inject code on the Control Panel pages. Basically, you'd insert some code on the edit_entry pages that looks like this:

```
$('.tag_input').attr('placeholder', 'Whatever you wanted for a placeholder');
```

Here's the Accessory Development reference:

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/accessories.html

Comment: Thanks, used the jquery and that did the trick! Was in the channel form anyway. Just thought I'd check I hadn't missed a setting/EE tag somewhere. 

Would be cool if this could be done with an EE tag...